# Build on OS X, target PowerPC 64

Tags: macos, llvm, powerpc

Target: PowerPC 64
Compiling on: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)

I don't need to run the code - just need to be able to generate, and then disassemble.

For the life of me, I can't figure out what magic combination of magic arguments for target/triple/arch/ect to use.